# Illegal configuration. Connection "cell" cannot have a prototype object as its destination

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 errors

```
"Illegal configuration. Connection "cell" cannot have a prototype object as
its destination"
```

Connections dont duplicate, cells are empty, without other controls in them. I try to clean project and rebuild it, but it didnt help me. How can I fix it? Thank you

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: What code do you want? @Chinmoy Debnath

Answer (score -9, accepted):

I found a solution. I delete and add new cell many times, and finally project build without errors

Comment: Honestly, I don't know why, but this worked... Was stuck with this issue for a while, and simply deleting and putting a new one works.

Comment: Yes, same for me. I copied and pasted a button through TableViews and it didn't work until i deleted and recreated.

Comment: No way to make this happen,.. any case it was not going to work

Answer (score 44):

Are you trying to link outlets of the cells (or elements of the cells) directly to the view controller? That would be a problem.

If you want your table view to always have the same content, you can change its content to "static cells" in the storyboard, and then you can link it like that.

If you want the table view cells to change dynamically, you cannot do it that way. You need to create a UITableViewCell subclass for your cells, and create the outlets there.

If this doesn't help at all, please explain your problem a bit better.

Comment: Ok, I try to explain my problem better. I have few controllers with tables. In each of two dynamic tables cells contains only text. In static table cells will contain some controls. I create classes for cells from dynamic tables. When I'm try to build my app - I have an error

Comment: Make sure that the view controller's outlets are not connecting to dynamic cells or their content. That is what the error is saying, maybe you have one of those connections by mistake?

Comment: Exactly as Tiago said. I had the same problem. What was wrong? I connected the elements' outlets (UILabel, UIImageView) of the storyboard directly to UIViewController. To combat it...create a custom UITableViewCell class (by adding new files to your project) and then from the Identity Inspector of the UITableViewCell change its class to the new one. Then connect the outlets to the custom cell and use that cell to your UIViewController (don't forget to import the header file)

Comment: He means that if you are trying to custom a static cell (ex make imageView visible hidden true/false) it gives this error.

If you have list view controller (let it be X) and Cell controller (let it be Y) your outlet should be in Y not in X

Answer (score 3):

You probably have an outlet from something like your view controller that's connected to a prototype cell in a table view. An outlet is a to-one relationship. The cell is going to be instantiated many times, so this doesn't make sense, and is an error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that the outlet from the ViewController was not connected to the desired object at all, although it might be connected from the desired object to the ViewController.

**for example:** the IBAction outlet can be seen from the UIButton's connection inspector for "touch up inside" as linked to the ViewController's IBAction method, but the ViewController's connection inspector will not link the IBAction method to the UIButton.

Answer (score 0):

**Same error** when I copied/pasted the admob banner view from the [official sample](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start) into my tableViewCell and connected the IBOutlet from viewController. So, Tiago Lira's explanation worked for me and I created the **custom cell class and added banner iboutlet there**. Thus the compile time error got resolved. The above question should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason for this error is that you have copied a storyboard item- It might be whole view controller or any sub element like the view, button, and label etc. So now the problem is that they have linked each other and now you have to find what is it and delete it.

> But if you have copied the whole view controller and you have checked
>   all possible links you could but still you getting error then this
>   trick is for you- Copy the main view of that view controller and
>   delete that VC then a make new VC and paste the copied view in that
>   VC, so your constraints are safe you just have to give top, bottom,
>   left and right constraints for the main view.