# Only first UILabel in Cell, UICollectionView Updated - Swift

Tags: ios, uiview, tags, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to update a UILabel that exists on my UICollectionView Cell. Although I am having the problem where **only the first cell gets updated with the new string**

I firstly tried to hook up an IBOutlet to the UILabel in the Cell, however got this problem:

```
Main.storyboard: error: Illegal Configuration: Connection "name" cannot have a prototype object as its destination.
```

Next, i tried to use a tag - however using this method, only one of the UICollectionView Cells get updated.

```
// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
    return 1000
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewCell! {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

    var nameLbl : UILabel? = self.collectionView.viewWithTag(100) as? UILabel;

    nameLbl?.text = "woof woof"

    return cell
}
```

How can i make it so that all of the cells are updated? I the future this label will change so it needs to be dynamic

I used to achieve this in Objective-C using:

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:LABEL_TAG];
```

Comment: You started down the right path with these outlets. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22784319/335858), it may be helpful.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks, although i got this method to work in Objective C, could my swift syntax be wrong maybe? Objective-C = UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:LABEL_TAG];

Comment: Here is [an answer with the corresponding syntax in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24096993/335858).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I tried what you suggested - however the same problem occurs, It also happens when i tired it on a fresh project

Comment: also found this which was useful: https://github.com/michaelbabiy/SwiftCollectionView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Swift counterpart for the Objective-C declaration:

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:LABEL_TAG];
```

is:

```
let label = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(LABEL_TAG) as UILabel
```

So replace:

```
var nameLbl : UILabel? = self.collectionView.viewWithTag(100) as? UILabel;
```

with:

```
let nameLbl = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(100) as UILabel
//or
//let nameLbl = cell.viewWithTag(100) as UILabel
```

You will then be able to write:

```
nameLbl.text = "woof woof"
```